# How to get autocomplete text widgets running on an iPad?

Tags: javascript, ajax, theming

I have a form with a couple of standard Drupal autocomplete text widgets, which work fine in desktop browsers.  However, they don't work in iPad/Safari -- the text field works properly, but I don't get any autocomplete activity.  What I can tell from a bit of log and jQuery hacking is that:

- The text field is catching both .click and .touchstart() events (and probably some other touch-related events as well), and
- The ajax call responsible for contacting the server to get the autocomplete results never gets made, presumably because it's not getting triggered.
- Elsewhere on the site, my jQuery installation is working fine, on both desktop and iPad -- there's lots of jquery-related Bootstrap stuff going on.
- I am also not getting autocomplete in Chrome/iPad, so it's not just a Safari thing.
- I confess to not knowing much about jQuery Mobile, and am not doing anything with it in the site.
- Via jQuery Update, I'm running jQuery 1.9 with Drupal 7.39, fully patched.  I've tried bumping jQuery up to 1.10 (as far as this version of jQuery Update will take me), but it still doesn't work.

I'm going to start diving down into the Drupal autocomplete source, but, while I'm doing that, does anybody have autocomplete widgets working on an iPad?

---

Update: I'm finding a lot of evidence (including my own experiments) that the keyup event is not handled by iPad (iOS really, I guess).  This is a problem for autocomplete, since some experimentation with autocomplete.js shows that it's the keyup handler that kicks off the search, via populatePopup().  I'm trying to rework the code to work with the keypress event, but it's early, and not going well thus far...

(FWIW, Android seems to handle keyup; at least, autocomplete is working on my old Galaxy Tab 2.)

---

Update #2: I got something working; yes, it's something of a hack.  There's a thread about what I did over at https://www.drupal.org/node/2594247, where I guess there's some chance that it might get into core.  We'll see...